# Is there any API to get list of ingredient that contains added alcohol

Tags: api, food

Is there any API to get list of ingredient that contains added Intoxicants/alcohol not the natural that just exists ?

Above would do the job for me for now, but if you are curious to know why I am asking this then some background...

I would like to develop an open source web app which will figure out if certain food products are halal or haram based on product's ingredients initially.

I already found a product ingredients database here - https://world.openfoodfacts.org/

But I am struggling to find a database for [Haram](http://www.islamforlife.co.uk/haram%20list.htm) ingredients or products.

[Haram food][2] is a big topic to cover but initially developing a simple engine would be a good start.

Comment: Here is some description of haram food - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haram#Food_and_intoxicants

Comment: Let me check this: you want a *two-step* process: product contains ingredient contains alcohol? Not just product contains alcohol?

Comment: @JanDoggen I want 1st one for now, as I think some products like fruits have alcohol in them naturally

Comment: Pierre from Open Food Facts :-)
We're keen on improving haram/non haram support, as well as any other ingredient detection. Volunteers needed :-)

Comment: When talking about `alcohol` do you really mean any [alcohol compound](https://www.britannica.com/science/alcohol)